# How to get the greatest number in a list of numbers using multiprocessing

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I have a list of random numbers and I would like to get the greatest number using **multiprocessing**.

This is the code I used to generate the list:

```
import random
randomlist = []
for i in range(100000000):
    n = random.randint(1,30000000)
    randomlist.append(n)
```

To get the greatest number using a serial process:

```
import time

greatest = 0 # global variable

def f(n):
    global greatest
    if n>greatest:
        greatest = n

if __name__ == "__main__":
    global greatest

    t2 = time.time()
    greatest = 0

    for x in randomlist:
        f(x)    
    
    print("serial process took:", time.time()-t2)
    print("greatest = ", greatest)
```

This is my try to get the greatest number using multiprocessing:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import time

greatest = 0 # the global variable

def f(n):
    global greatest
    if n>greatest:
        greatest = n

if __name__ == "__main__":
    global greatest
    greatest = 0
    t1 = time.time()
    p = Pool() #(processes=3) 
    result = p.map(f,randomlist)
    p.close()
    p.join()
    print("pool took:", time.time()-t1)
    print("greatest = ", greatest)
```

The output here is 0. It is clear that there is no global variable. How can I fix this without affecting the performance?

Comment: When you use multiprocessing, each process has its own copy of the global variable.

Comment: If you want to share a global variable, use multithreading, not multiprocessing.

Comment: But then you need mutual exclusion, which will effectively serialize it.

Comment: Instead, you should have each process calculate the maximum of a different chunk of the list, and return that. Then you can get the maximum of those.

Comment: I used the same strategy in my answer as @Barmar suggested to compute local maximum the get the global maximum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @Barmar, divide your `randomlist` into chunk then process local maximum from each chunk and finally compute global maximum from `local_maximum_list`:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import numpy as np
import random
import time

CHUNKSIZE = 10000

def local_maximum(l):
    m = max(l)
    print(f"Local maximum: {m}")
    return m

if __name__ == '__main__':
    randomlist = np.random.randint(1, 30000000, 100000000)

    start = time.time()
    chunks = (randomlist[i:i+CHUNKSIZE]
                  for i in range(0, len(randomlist), CHUNKSIZE))

    with mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count()) as pool:
        local_maximum_list = pool.map(local_maximum, chunks)
    print(f"Global maximum: {max(local_maximum_list)}")
    end = time.time()
    print(f"MP Elapsed time: {end-start:.2f}s")
```

**Performance**

It's very interesting how the creation of the random list impacts the performance of multiprocessing

```
Scenario 1:
randomlist = np.random.randint(1, 30000000, 100000000)
MP Elapsed time: 1.63s

Scenario 2:
randomlist = np.random.randint(1, 30000000, 100000000).tolist()
MP Elapsed time: 6.02s

Scenario 3
randomlist = [random.randint(1, 30000000) for _ in range(100000000)]
MP Elapsed time: 7.14s

Scenario 4:
randomlist = list(np.random.randint(1, 30000000, 100000000))
MP Elapsed time: 184.28s

Scenario 5:
randomlist = []
for _ in range(100000000):
    n = random.randint(1, 30000000)
    randomlist.append(n)
MP Elapsed time: 7.52s
```

Comment: Many thanks. I will use this method. Is there any solution without using chunks? even if using multithreading. My end goal is using more than one core

Comment: This method uses all your cores (`mp.cpu_count()`). As you cannot share a variable between processes, you have to split your unique variable `randomlist` into chunks. With multiprocessing, you have no choice.

Comment: Is it possible to use list instead of numpy-array? I converted randomlist to list and it affected the performance alot.  I am trying to use the same method with list of words (strings).

Comment: The bottleneck is the creation of `randomlist` not the multiprocessing part. Try to use a comprehension to create the list, it's faster than your loop: `randomlist = [random.randint(1, 30000000) for _ in range(100000000)` or `randomlist = np.random.randint(1, 30000000, 100000000).tolist()`

Comment: The performance effect was after the creation of the list. Try the same code you posted but add this line `randomlist = list(randomlist)`

Comment: You're right. `randomlist = list(randomlist)` is the worst scenario to create the `randomlist`. Check my updated answer, please.